# PHP str_pad and strlen within preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, strlen

I'm attempting to output a certain number of zeros depending on the number of digits. My code doesn't output what I want.

```
$x = '12345';
$y = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', str_pad('',(12-strlen("$1")),0), $x);
echo "y = $y";

# expected output: y = 0000000 (7 zeros)
# output: y = 0000000000 (10 zeros)
```

Comment: You will need http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [dev-null-dweller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258674/dev-null-dweller) said in the comments you should use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
// This requires PHP 5.3+
$x = '12345';
$y = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($m){
    return(str_pad('', 12 - strlen($m[0]), 0));
}, $x);
echo "y = $y";
```

Comment: Thanks to you both. This works nicely. I didn't know how to use the preg_replace_callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I did this which works:

```
<?php
$x = '12345';
$y = str_pad(preg_replace('/(\d+)/', "0", $x), 12 - strlen($x), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "y = $y";
```

There is also this regular expression version too:

```
$y = str_pad(preg_replace('/\d/', "0", $x), 12 - strlen($x), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

There is also this, if you wan't the final output to look like: `0012345`

```
$y = str_pad($x, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: $x is used as an example. the value in strlen needs to be the search string result.